# Understanding for-nested loop

Tags: java, loops

```
 public static void main(String[] args)  {

     int count, innerCount;
     for(count=0;count<=3;count++)
     {
         System.out.println("Count is" + count);
         for(innerCount=0; innerCount<count;innerCount++)
             System.out.print("Hi, innerCount is"+ innerCount);
     }
 }

}
```

Output:
Count is0

Count is1

Hi, innerCount is0Count is2

Hi, innerCount is0Hi, innerCount is1Count is3

Hi, innerCount is0Hi, innerCount is1Hi, innerCount is2

Can someone explain this for nested loop to  me, please? When it is Count = 0 and 1 why is it not printing out any innerCounts? Also howcome innercounts are printing right next to Count? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When it is Count = 0 and 1 why is it not printing out any innerCounts?

It is. When `count` is 0, the inner loop never executes its body, because the `innerCount<count` condition is never true (`0<0` is false). When `count` is 1, the inner loop executes once, when `innerCount` is `0` (printing "Hi, innerCount is0"), because `0<1` is true. It doesn't execute a second time because `1<1` is false.

> Also howcome innercounts are printing right next to Count? Thanks.

Because you're using [`System.out.print`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29), which doesn't append newlines. [`System.out.println`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) appends newlines, if you want to use that.

Comment: Thanks but I still didn't understand how it skipped the inner loop the second time around. When Count = 1.

Comment: @user: It didn't. It output "Hi, innerCount is0". Because `innerCount<count` when `innerCount` is 0 and `count` is 1. And so immediately after outputting "Count is1", it output "Hi, innerCount is0". Things will get a **lot** clearer if you change the `System.out.print("Hi, innerCount is"+ innerCount);` line to `System.out.println("count = " + count + ", innerCount = " + innerCount);`. (Note I'm using `println` there, and outputting both `count` and `innerCount`, so it's clear what's going on.)

Comment: Yeah, but why isn't in the next line ? When I put in <= it prints out " Hi, innerCount is0" next to it. Yeah this is clearer, thanks. It's printing what is less than the count at that time.

Comment: @user: Again: `print` doesn't add a newline. `println` does. You're using a mix of the two, which is confusing you. Make the change I suggested above, and things will be a **lot** clearer.

Comment: I understand what it is doing your way but why is it not showing innercount the otherway? Or it does that I am not able to see it.

Comment: Sorry, i am new to this stuff so its confusing.

Comment: @user: It **is** showing `innerCount`. Please carefully re-read the above. I don't know how to say it more clearly. When `innerCount` is less than `count`, which is what you've asked for in `for(innerCount=0; innerCount<count;innerCount++)`, it's showing `innerCount`. When `innerCount` is 0 and `count` is 1, then `innerCount<count` and it outputs `innerCount` by saying "Hi, innerCount is0".

Comment: After your edit, I understood what the program was  doing. I am just having trouble understanding the way it is outputted using 
System.out.print(Hi, InnerCount is" + InnerCount);

Comment: Nevermind, I was getting confused because of "system.out.print". I got it now.Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It prints out Count = 0 and Count = 1 first because your condition in the inner loop is innerCount < count so it is skipped the first time since both innerCount and count = 0.

`System.out.print` doesn't append newlines. Use `System.out.println` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`innerCount<count` is your problem

make it <= and you will get a printout for 0

as someone already pointed out, you do get a result when count = 1 already

Comment: Well it's not necessarily a *problem* -- it's hard to tell though. :-)

Comment: Yes, I understand  that innerCount<count but shouldn't it print out innerCount = 0 when Count = 1 and so on. Or it doesn't because Count equals to 0?

Comment: when count = 0, innerCount < count will never match as 0 is not < 0, its <= 0